# Capistrano deploy and composer install issue

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php, capistrano, capistrano3

I am totally new on composer and I try to figure out how to deploy my code from my local machine to my sandbox machine but it seems that the whole process ends on `composer install`

What I did until now:

- Initiate a new `git` repository and push it on `GitHub`
- I made my local project using composer for installing my dependencies
- I setup a new `VirtualBox` `Ubuntu Server`
- I configured the `SSH` so I can connect from my local computer to `Ubuntu Server` with no password ( I am using ssh keys )
- I setup my LAMP
- I setup the composer so it can run from bash using just `composer args`
- I config my `git` on the server
- I have add my server `SSH` key on my GitHub account so I can interact with GitHub without using passwords
- I have setup my web site on my `Ubuntu Server`
- I did my `hosts` file changes to be able to access my web site using a domain.

All of the above steps are working properly. I have try the deployment process manual, and it works as it should.

The only problem I had was the composer, that returns me the following error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Your configuration does not allow connections to http://wpackagist.org/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.
```

But by modify my `composer.json` and replacing the following line:

```
"url" : "http://wpackagist.org"
```

with this:

```
"url" : "https://wpackagist.org"
```

the composer runs properly too, and all the dependencies are installed as it should.

### The Capistrano issue

Now in my `staging.rb` I have the following tasks:

```
namespace :deploy do

 desc 'Copy repository files on my root'
 task :files_to_root do
     on roles( :app ) do
         info 'Starting copying the files'
         execute "cp -a #{fetch( :deploy_to ) }/current/. #{fetch( :deploy_to ) }"
     end
 end

 desc 'Run composer installation'
 task :run_composer do
     on roles( :app ) do
         info 'Starting run composer'
         execute 'sed -i -e \'s/http\:\/\/wpackagist/https\:\/\/wpackagist/\' composer.json'
         execute 'composer install'
     end
 end

 after :finishing, :files_to_root
 after :finishing, :run_composer
```

end

But when I run my `cap staging deploy` and the script arrives to `:run_composer` task the console logs the following lines:

```
INFO [89538861] Running composer install as merianos@192.168.1.5
DEBUG [89538861] Command: composer install
DEBUG [89538861]    Loading composer repositories with package information
DEBUG [89538861]    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
DEBUG [89538861]    Nothing to install or update
DEBUG [89538861]    Writing lock file
DEBUG [89538861]    Generating autoload files
INFO [89538861] Finished in 5.563 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

And if I try after the deploy to run `composer install` on my server it will install all the dependencies.

Does anyone know what is the reason the composer doesn't run when I execute it from Capistrano ?

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/capistrano/composer ?

Comment: Nope. Finally I start using the Rocketeer that is much better. Anyway, thank you for your response :)